# Kafka JDBCSinkConnector Schema exception: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload"

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm  trying to tranfer data from Kafka topic to Postgres using JDBCSinkConnector. After all manipulations such as creating the topic, creating the stream, creating sink connector with configuration and produce data into topic throught python - connect logs returns the following result:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration
```

This is the code of JSON Schema (sch.json):

```
{
    "schema":{
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
         {
        "type":"int32",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "id"
        },
        {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": false,
        "field":"url"
        ],
        "optional":false,
        "name": "test_data"
    },
    "payload":{
        "id": 12,
        "url":"some_url"
       
    }
}
```

This is code for kafka-connect:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/sink-jdbc-postgre-01/config \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "connector.class"                    : "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "connection.url"                     : "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/",
    "topics"                             : "test_topic06",
    "key.converter"                      : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable"       : "true",
    "value.converter"                    : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable"     : "true",  
    "connection.user"                    : "postgres",
    "connection.password"                : "*******",
    "auto.create"                        : true,
    "auto.evolve"                        : true,
    "insert.mode"                        : "insert",
    "pk.mode"                            : "record_key",
    "pk.fields"                          : "MESSAGE_KEY"
}'
```

This is python code for producing data to Kafka:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json 
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['127.0.0.1:9092'],value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))
with open("../data/sch.json", 'r') as file:
    read = file.read()
    for i in range(1):
        producer.send("test_topic06", value=read)
producer.close()
```

Then I tried to change  `"key.converter.schemas.enable"` and `"value.converter.schemas.enable"` to false, but its all the same result in the log.

Full log:

```
2021-04-01 09:20:41,342] INFO MonitoringInterceptorConfig values: 
connect            |    confluent.monitoring.interceptor.publishMs = 15000
connect            |    confluent.monitoring.interceptor.topic = _confluent-monitoring
connect            |  (io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringInterceptorConfig)
connect            | [2021-04-01 09:20:41,344] INFO ProducerConfig values: 
connect            |    acks = -1
connect            |    batch.size = 16384
connect            |    bootstrap.servers = [broker:29092]
connect            |    buffer.memory = 33554432
connect            |    client.dns.lookup = default
connect            |    client.id = confluent.monitoring.interceptor.connector-consumer-sink-jdbc-postgre-01-0
connect            |    compression.type = lz4
connect            |    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
connect            |    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
connect            |    enable.idempotence = false
connect            |    interceptor.classes = []
connect            |    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
connect            |    linger.ms = 500
connect            |    max.block.ms = 60000
connect            |    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1
connect            |    max.request.size = 10485760
connect            |    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
connect            |    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
connect            |    metric.reporters = []
connect            |    metrics.num.samples = 2
connect            |    metrics.recording.level = INFO
connect            |    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
connect            |    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
connect            |    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
connect            |    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
connect            |    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
connect            |    request.timeout.ms = 30000
connect            |    retries = 10
connect            |    retry.backoff.ms = 500
connect            |    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
connect            |    sasl.jaas.config = null
connect            |    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
connect            |    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
connect            |    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
connect            |    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
connect            |    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
connect            |    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
connect            |    sasl.login.class = null
connect            |    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
connect            |    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
connect            |    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
connect            |    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
connect            |    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
connect            |    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
connect            |    security.providers = null
connect            |    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
connect            |    ssl.cipher.suites = null
connect            |    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
connect            |    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
connect            |    ssl.key.password = null
connect            |    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
connect            |    ssl.keystore.location = null
connect            |    ssl.keystore.password = null
connect            |    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
connect            |    ssl.protocol = TLS
connect            |    ssl.provider = null
connect            |    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
connect            |    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
connect            |    ssl.truststore.location = null
connect            |    ssl.truststore.password = null
connect            |    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
connect            |    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
connect            |    transactional.id = null
connect            |    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
connect            |  (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig)
connect            | [2021-04-01 09:20:41,349] INFO Kafka version: 5.5.0-ce (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
connect            | [2021-04-01 09:20:41,349] INFO Kafka commitId: 6068e5d52c5e294e (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
connect            | [2021-04-01 09:20:41,349] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1617268841349 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
connect            | [2021-04-01 09:20:41,349] INFO interceptor=confluent.monitoring.interceptor.connector-consumer-sink-jdbc-postgre-01-0 created for client_id=connector-consumer-sink-jdbc-postgre-01-0 client_type=CONSUMER session= cluster=K4nfs8sOSWCoI2_jEFzZ1Q group=connect-sink-jdbc-postgre-01 (io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringInterceptor)
connect            | [2021-04-01 09:20:41,361] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=sink-jdbc-postgre-01-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
connect            | org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:492)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:469)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:325)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:228)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:196)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:184)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
connect            |    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
connect            |    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
connect            |    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
connect            |    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
connect            |    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
connect            | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:359)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$2(WorkerSinkTask.java:492)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
connect            |    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
connect            |    ... 13 more
connect            | [2021-04-01 09:20:41,363] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=sink-jdbc-postgre-01-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
connect            | [2021-04-01 09:20:41,364] INFO Stopping task (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask)
connect            | [2021-04-01 09:20:41,366] INFO [Producer clientId=confluent.monitoring.interceptor.connector-consumer-sink-jdbc-postgre-01-0] Cluster ID: K4nfs8sOSWCoI2_jEFzZ1Q (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)
connect            | [2021-04-01 09:20:41,370] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-sink-jdbc-postgre-01-0, groupId=connect-sink-jdbc-postgre-01] Revoke previously assigned partitions test_topic06-2, test_topic06-0, test_topic06-1 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
connect            | [2021-04-01 09:20:41,370] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-sink-jdbc-postgre-01-0, groupId=connect-sink-jdbc-postgre-01] Member connector-consumer-sink-jdbc-postgre-01-0-a6013ad5-a778-4372-a9ab-a0c77119150b sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator broker:29092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) due to the consumer is being closed (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
connect            | [2021-04-01 09:20:41,379] INFO Publish thread interrupted for client_id=connector-consumer-sink-jdbc-postgre-01-0 client_type=CONSUMER session= cluster=K4nfs8sOSWCoI2_jEFzZ1Q group=connect-sink-jdbc-postgre-01 (io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringInterceptor)
connect            | [2021-04-01 09:20:41,396] INFO Publishing Monitoring Metrics stopped for client_id=connector-consumer-sink-jdbc-postgre-01-0 client_type=CONSUMER session= cluster=K4nfs8sOSWCoI2_jEFzZ1Q group=connect-sink-jdbc-postgre-01 (io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringInterceptor)
connect            | [2021-04-01 09:20:41,397] INFO [Producer clientId=confluent.monitoring.interceptor.connector-consumer-sink-jdbc-postgre-01-0] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer)
connect            | [2021-04-01 09:20:41,403] INFO Closed monitoring interceptor for client_id=connector-consumer-sink-jdbc-postgre-01-0 client_type=CONSUMER session= cluster=K4nfs8sOSWCoI2_jEFzZ1Q group=connect-sink-jdbc-postgre-01 (io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringInterceptor)
```

Comment: You have no keys, so don't use the json converter for it, only the values. Also, you might want to make sure you're not including linebreaks in your message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the Connector to parse a `JSON` key

```
"key.converter"                      : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"key.converter.schemas.enable"       : "true",
```

but you're not pushing any key

```
producer.send("test_topic06", value=read)
```

Could you

- set your `key.converter` to `org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter`

or

- Pass also the key with the same `{schema: {}, payload:{}}` structure with

```
producer.send("test_topic06", key=key_value, value=read)
```