# Unable to get kafka connect redshift connector working

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-kafka-python

Following the question and suggestions here: [Kafka JDBCSinkConnector Schema exception: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902577/kafka-jdbcsinkconnector-schema-exception-jsonconverter-with-schemas-enable-requ), I am trying to sink records into redshift using redshift connector and a producer written in python. Here is the connector config:

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.aws.redshift.RedshiftSinkConnector
aws.redshift.port=5439
confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
tasks.max=2
topics=test_topic_3
aws.redshift.password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws.redshift.domain=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.redshift.amazonaws.com
aws.redshift.database=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
confluent.topic.replication.factor=1
aws.redshift.user=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
auto.create=true
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
pk.mode=kafka
```

The content in the schema file is as under:

```
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"url"}],"optional":false,"name":"test_data"},"payload":{"id":12,"url":"some_url"}}
```

and the python code is:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers="xxxxxxxxxxxxx",value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))
with open("connector_test_schema.json", 'r') as file:
    read = file.read()
    for i in range(1):
        producer.send("test_topic_3", key='abc'.encode('utf-8'), value=read)
producer.close()
```

I still get the following error:

> [Worker-0fbc0b18922b147e0] org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.

Is there something that's wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: I feel like you're double-encoding your JSON data. Please show `kafka-console-consumer` output

Comment: you were right, double encoding was causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @OneCricketeer and confirmed, encoding was done twice, causing it to fail.

Solution: Only encode the string read from the JSON file

```
value_serializer=lambda v: v.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Great. How did you fix it?

Comment: I didn't need the json.dumps since import from file was bringing it in as a string already.

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and solution source code explaining how it solved the problem.